# How to replace bxSlider controls with Font Awesome icons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using bxslider in my web page, but how can i change the next prev to font awesome icon? is it possible? Which code should i change? Thanks.

Below is my html and js code.

HTML:

```html
<div class = "container-fluid">
   <div id="slider1">
   <div class="">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="ribbon ribbon-pt-acc">Account</div>
      <img src="../../images/game/assassin.jpg" class="panel-img img-responsive">
       <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="offer-title"><h5 class="text-danger">Player of the Month: Messi</h5></div>
        <div class="offer-desc text-muted small">
          FIFA 15
          <br />
          Xbox ONE
        </div>
        <h4 class="txt-1line"><b>RM 103.90</b></h4>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="ribbon ribbon-pt-acc">Currency</div>
      <img src="../../images/game/ff-tactics.jpg" class="panel-img img-responsive">
       <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="offer-title"><h5 class="text-danger">5,000 GOLD</h5></div>
        <div class="offer-desc text-muted small">
          1 Gold = RM 0.70
          <br />
          Aegwynn - Alliance
        </div>
        <h4 class="txt-1line"><b>RM 23.90</b></h4>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="ribbon ribbon-pt-acc">Item</div>
      <img src="../../images/game/harvest-moon.jpg" class="panel-img img-responsive">
       <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="offer-title"><h5 class="text-danger">Legendary Weapon's Raw Materia</h5></div>
        <div class="offer-desc text-muted small">
          Guild Wars 2
          <br />
          All Servers
        </div>
        <h4 class="txt-1line"><b>RM 486.50</b></h4>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>    
   <div class="">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="ribbon ribbon-pt-acc">Boosting</div>
      <img src="../../images/game/hero.jpg" class="panel-img img-responsive">
       <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="offer-title"><h5 class="text-danger">10,000 GOLD</h5></div>
        <div class="offer-desc text-muted small">
          1 Gold = RM 0.007
          <br />
          Aefwynn - Alliance
        </div>
        <h4 class="txt-1line"><b>RM 48.50</b></h4>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="ribbon ribbon-pt-acc">Card</div>
      <img src="../../images/game/lol.jpg" class="panel-img img-responsive">
       <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="offer-title"><h5 class="text-danger">Legendary Weapon's Raw Materia</h5></div>
        <div class="offer-desc text-muted small">
          World of Warcraft
          <br />
          Firetree - Horde
        </div>
        <h4 class="txt-1line"><b>RM 263.10</b></h4>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="ribbon ribbon-pt-acc">Currency</div>
      <img src="../../images/game/reckoning.jpg" class="panel-img img-responsive">
       <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="offer-title"><h5 class="text-danger">Something os Something Epicness</h5></div>
        <div class="offer-desc text-muted small">
          Guild Wars 2
          <br />
          All Servers
        </div>
        <h4 class="txt-1line"><b>RM 82.50</b></h4>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="ribbon ribbon-pt-acc">Account</div>
      <img src="../../images/game/sanguo.jpg" class="panel-img img-responsive">
       <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="offer-title"><h5 class="text-danger">Player of the Month: Messi</h5></div>
        <div class="offer-desc text-muted small">
          FIFA 15
          <br />
          Xbox ONE
        </div>
        <h4 class="txt-1line"><b>RM 103.90</b></h4>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Here are bxslider Javascript:

```js
/** RESET AND LAYOUT
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto 60px;
 padding: 0;
 *zoom: 1;
}

.bx-wrapper img {
 max-width: 100%;
 display: block;
}

/** THEME
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
 border:  5px solid #fff;
 left: -5px;
 background: #fff;
 
 /*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/
 -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
 -moz-transform: translatez(0);
     -ms-transform: translatez(0);
     -o-transform: translatez(0);
     transform: translatez(0);
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -30px;
 width: 100%;
}

/* LOADER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-loading {
 min-height: 50px;
 background: url(images/bx_loader.gif) center center no-repeat #fff;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 2000;
}

/* PAGER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: .85em;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #666;
 padding-top: 20px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager .bx-pager-item,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-controls-auto-item {
 display: inline-block;
 *zoom: 1;
 *display: inline;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
 background: #666;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 display: block;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 margin: 0 5px;
 outline: 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active {
 background: #000;
}

/* DIRECTION CONTROLS (NEXT / PREV) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
 left: 10px;
 background: url(images/controls.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
 right: 10px;
 background: url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -43px -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover {
 background-position: 0 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover {
 background-position: -43px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -16px;
 outline: 0;
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 z-index: 9999;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a.disabled {
 display: none;
}

/* AUTO CONTROLS (START / STOP) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
 text-align: center;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start {
 display: block;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 width: 10px;
 height: 11px;
 outline: 0;
 background: url(images/controls.png) -86px -11px no-repeat;
 margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start.active {
 background-position: -86px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop {
 display: block;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 width: 9px;
 height: 11px;
 outline: 0;
 background: url(images/controls.png) -86px -44px no-repeat;
 margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop.active {
 background-position: -86px -33px;
}

/* PAGER WITH AUTO-CONTROLS HYBRID LAYOUT */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-pager {
 text-align: left;
 width: 80%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-controls-auto {
 right: 0;
 width: 35px;
}

/* IMAGE CAPTIONS */

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: #666\9;
 background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.75);
 width: 100%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption span {
 color: #fff;
 font-family: Arial;
 display: block;
 font-size: .85em;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show your html please..

Comment: Basically you see that `bx-wrapper .bx-prev` and .`bx-wrapper .bx-next` CSS, just remove `background` from that and add respective `fa` classes to that particular elements

Comment: wouuld you provide some example? i am using fa-chevron- arrow

Answer (score 4):

Just try to add `fa` - `icons` as below:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
        prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>'
});
```

For other options check this **[solution here](http://bxslider.com/examples/custom-next-prev-selectors)**

Comment: still not able to fix the problem.

Comment: i already added the screenshots and also initialization code, hope you can help me. Thanks you so much.

Comment: If this is "still unable to fix the problem" I am next to certain it is because you have not compensated for the text-indent set to -999em on the .bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a default CSS if you are loading the bxslider CSS

Answer (score 0):

If you add the font-awesome icons as nextText & prevText, remove the text-indent property from the css of bxSlider. The selector is .bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a. This rule makes sense when using the standard values, but if you use the *text-properties to add icons, as in our case, the indentation hides the icons outside of the viewport.